# Avoiding particle "pop in" affect for Unity2D starfield

Tags: unity

I've adapted a 3D starfield particle system for top-down 2D use. I'm aiming for what's shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80G_wRQRhXc), which was based on [this tutorial](http://www.blenderfreak.com/blog/post/creating-infinite-starfield-unity3d/).

I've managed to reproduce the 3D particle system and I have a top-down view working correctly.

However, I'm trying to figure out what needs to change to achieve the effect in the first video. The difference for me is that this logic randomly spawns new particles within a radius around the camera, which in 3D seems fine, as if the stars are appearing as you travel towards them. But in "2D" this breaks because the player/camera can only move in two dimensions.

I need to find a way for stars to spawn off-screen, they can't "pop in" randomly as the player moves. Unfortunately I'm not sure how the developer of that video achieved it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Starfield : MonoBehaviour {
    private Transform tx;
    private ParticleSystem particleSystem;
    private ParticleSystem.Particle[] points;

    public int starsMax;
    public float starSize;
    public float starDistance;
    private float starDistanceSqr;

    void Awake() {
        particleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        tx = transform;
        starDistanceSqr = starDistance * starDistance;
    }

    void Start() {
        points = new ParticleSystem.Particle[starsMax];

        for (int i = 0; i < starsMax; i++) {
            points[i].position = Random.insideUnitSphere * starDistance + tx.position;
            points[i].color = Color.white;
            points[i].size = starSize;
        }
    }

    void Update() {
        for (int i = 0; i < starsMax; i++) {
            if ((points[i].position - tx.position).sqrMagnitude > starDistanceSqr) {
                points[i].position = Random.insideUnitSphere.normalized * starDistance + tx.position;
            }
        }

        particleSystem.SetParticles(points, points.Length);
    }
}
```